# Why 10GbE card cannot negotiate 10Gbit with Windows 2012R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge, ethernet, 10gbethernet, broadcom

### The Problem

I've got four identical blade servers.

I've got Windows Server 2012 R2 on **one** blade and Xen on all the others.

**On the Windows-hosted server** (only) the 10GbE NICs **cannot negotiate 10Gbit**.  They settle at 1Gbit only.

10GbE on Xen hosts works properly.

### The Environment

I've got DELL PowerEdge M1000e chassis with:

- 2x M8024-k 10GbE switch (A1, A2)
- 4x M620 **identical** blades with following NIC:

  - slot A: Broadcom NetXtreme 10GbE 2P 57810s (the 10GbE card this issue is about)
  - slot B: Broadcom NetXtreme GbE 4P 5719S (not related to issue, I hope)

All the available firmwares are identical and up-to-date.

### Additional info & diagnostic

- The machine has previously been used under some *nix system (probably also Xen) and previous sysadmin had left no notice of any such problems (which would otherwise be expected). I therefore assume it was working properly.
- This happens on both ports. Both ports are on single card though.
- When I try to set speed manually at 10Gbit, I get Windowsy *"network cable not attached"* status.
- Windows has all the latest drivers.
- As stated above, the problem does not appear on Xen-hosted servers. It's Windows only.
- The configuration on both switches (A1 and A2) has been reviewed, ports *are* set to auto-negotiation and I found no other differences in the port configurations between Windows and Xen-assigned ports.
- This was the only machine with NIC partitioning enabled (NPAR+SR-IOV), but I have disabled it and it made no change.

### The Question

Since I still believe it might be some weird Windows issue, I have posted this question to exclude any possible **software sources** of the problem, especially those which might be Windows-specific.

Do you have any hints where to look and what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you check the driver versions? Broadcom is - ah - reputed for - ah - interesting definitions of high quality, at least in the past.

Comment: What driver do you have installed?  Last time I remember setting up a 10 Gb link, I needed a particular driver to get it working at 10Gb... so that's where I'd look first.

Comment: It's "Broadcom 18.2.0 / DELL 17.8.4.2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was hardware, not software. And apparently very simple one.

Once the blade has been shut down, **physically removed** from the chassis and then **reattached** (at the same slot), we have finally attained a proper 10G link.

Just that :)